# How can I delete all the files that end with "2"?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, directory, rm

I accidentally copied two times the files of a backup, so now I have got two identical files, the only difference is that one of two terminates with a space followed by "2".

Example:

```
urh 2.sh
urh.sh
```

or

```
vim tut
vim tut 2
```

How can I recursively delete all these duplicates via bash in a single command?

Comment: `2.sh` - here the file has a extension, but for the next case it does nto

Comment: @Inian yes, and?

Comment: That means they are completely different and couldn't have been created by the same process. Can you give us some more examples of your file names? can you have files like `foo22` that should be kept? How about `foo.2.bar`? How can we know if a file needs to be deleted?

Comment: @terdon all the files that has to be deleted have a space and then "2" in the end of filename.

Comment: So `urh 2.sh` should _not_ be deleted? What about a file called `foo bar 2 bax bot.txt`?

Comment: @terdon urh 2.sh should be deleted. A file called foo bar 2 bax bot.txt should NOT be deleted.

Comment: Thanks @Rayleigh . I checked with you command, and it seems that they are the files to remove. But If I entry the `find -name "* 2.*" -exec rm {} \;` it gives me an input choice to "override" a certain single file, so it's not automatic and I have to enter for each file! How can I make this automatic without any input choice?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the exact output you get when trying that `find` command?

Comment: "Override" should apply to permissions, which suggests some of these files were created by other users or have been intentionally protected. There is a `-f` (force) option to rm, but it would be foolhardy to use it without understanding why it is needed here.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thanks, it fixed the problem!

Comment: You have apparently solved your problem, but please **do not abandon the post**. There are still 2 things to do: (1) Add clarification and attempts in the question by editing it, not in the comments. Pay special attention to make the problem well-defined by giving an appropriate description. `urh 2.sh` does not end in ` 2`, but you want to delete it. (2) Write your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find and then delete ...like this

first check if the list of files to be deleted are correct:

```
find /path/to/the/folder -name "* 2" -print0| xargs -0 -n1 ls
```

and then delete

```
find /path/to/the/folder -name "* 2" -print0| xargs -0 rm -f
```

make sure you have backup before deleting anything incase anything goes wrong...

cheers,

SK

Comment: Since you're assuming `-print0` is available in `find`, you'd probably have `-ls` and `-delete` too, making the `xargs` unnecessary.

Comment: true...thanks... not sure about the assumption though.. why would print0 not be available in find?

Comment: It's not a [standard feature](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html), so there may be some system somewhere that doesn't have it. The GNU and FreeBSD versions do have it though. But now that I look, Busybox's find does have `-print0` but not `-delete` or `-ls`, so that would be one set of utils where my suggestion wouldn't work.

Comment: cool... really appreciate though to make some nice suggestions... cheers

Answer (score 0):

The [bash-shell glob expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) (`man 7 glob`) should be enough for you case.

```
rm ./*" 2"*
```

This would remove every file in the current directory whose name contains at least one instance of the substring " 2".